# how do I pass an array from laravel to js

Tags: javascript, laravel

Need to pass the array to JS

An array is received from the controller (collection). I get all the ID

```
$top_menu->pluck('id')
```

[image]
js script

```
// 1 part of the menu
but_g_menu. onclick = function() {
    if(id_g_menu. style . display == "none")  {
        id_g_menu.style . display= "";
    }
    else  { id_g_menu.style . display = "none"; }
}
// 2 part of the menu
var id_menu = new Array('1111','2222','3333');
startList = function allclose() {
    for (i=0; i < id_menu.length; i++){
        document.getElementById(id_menu[i]).style.display = "none";
    }
}
function openMenu(id){
    for (i=0; i < id_menu.length; i++){
        if (id != id_menu[i]){
            document.getElementById(id_menu[i]).style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == "block"){
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
    }else{
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
    }
}
window.onload=startList;
```

need to pass the category ID to js `var id_menu = new Array(`
or change the js in some other way.
I don't understand much about js.
I am grateful in advance for any information!

I manage to convey it like this:

```
var id_menu = json_encode($top_menu->pluck('id'));  
var id_menu = json_encode([1,2,3,4,16,19]);
```

but the script does not work

```
var id_menu = new (json_encode($top_menu->pluck('id')));  
var id_menu = new (json_encode([1,2,3,4,16,19]));
```

this doesn't work either

Comment: `id_g_menu.style . display = "none";` is wrong syntax (too much white space) - it has to be `id_g_menu.style.display = "none";`

Comment: it still doesn't work )) even with spaces, it works like this: new Array('1111','2222','3333');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to echo the json encoded array to the js.

```
var id_menu = {{json_encode($top_menu->pluck('id'))}};
```

Or you can use the blade helper

```
var id_menu = @json($top_menu->pluck('id'));
```